# Stagnant of Luigi Task Scheduler

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, luigi, visualizer

I want to use luigi(2.8) task scheduler, but setting up it does not finish.

At first, I use luigid command simply.

```
luigid
```

Next, I access to localhost:8082 via Firefox.
It shows moving dotted circles instead of icons.
I can not move to any pages.(only URL changed)

Do you know a similar situation and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to run something. `luigid` doesn't start any tasks, it just the scheduler daemon. Try running a workflow on it.